# Mongoose - Try another server if the first one can't be reached

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working on a semester project using mongoose (nodejs project) and my University is blocking a lot of ports.

I was looking for a way to try to connect() to the first server and catch the error if it can't be reached to try connect() to a localhost mongodb instance but all solutions I found are not working.

Is there a clean way to handle the error and manage it like this ?

In advance, Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const db = mongoose.connection

let uri = '<FIRSTSERVER_URI>'

let options = {
  user: '<FIRSTSERVER_USERNAME>'
  pass: '<FIRSTSERVER_PASSWORD>'
}

mongoose.connect(uri, options, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    mongoose.connection.close()
    setTimeout(function () {
      uri = '<LOCALHOST_URI>'
      options = {
        user: '<LOCALHOST_USERNAME>',
        pass: '<LOCALHOST_PASSWORD>'
      }
      mongoose.connect(uri, options)
    }, 3000)
  }
})

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'))
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
})
```

Comment: Hi JazzBrotha, Thank you for you quick answer.